# How to extract first 2 digits and last 3 digits from a string and concatenating them in unix?

Tags: unix

i'm trying to extract 032020 from Rockssa_BASDI_Rasdwe_03012020.txt

tried the below command able to get `03012020`

`echo Rockssa_BASDI_Rasdwe_03012020.txt|awk '{print substr($1,length($1)-11,8)}'`

please guide on how to get just `03` the first 2 charaters and `2020` last 4 characters and concat them as `032020`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is the following

`cut -c 1,2,5-8`

like so

```sh
$ echo Rockssa_BASDI_Rasdwe_03012020.txt | awk '{print substr($1,length($1)-11,8)}' | cut -c 1,2,5-8
$ 032020
```